# C - How do I receive a bit from a bit field as a parameter in a function?

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller, bit, bit-fields

I have a bit field defined like that (it is from a microcontroller library, so it looks a bit different):

```
typedef union {
    byte Byte;
    struct {
        byte PTAD0       :1;
        byte PTAD1       :1;                                       
        byte PTAD2       :1;
        byte PTAD3       :1;
        byte PTAD4       :1;
        byte PTAD5       :1;
        byte             :1;
        byte             :1;
    } Bits;
} PTADSTR;
extern volatile PTADSTR _PTAD @0x00000000;
#define PTAD                            _PTAD.Byte
#define PTAD_PTAD0                      _PTAD.Bits.PTAD0
#define PTAD_PTAD1                      _PTAD.Bits.PTAD1
#define PTAD_PTAD2                      _PTAD.Bits.PTAD2
#define PTAD_PTAD3                      _PTAD.Bits.PTAD3
#define PTAD_PTAD4                      _PTAD.Bits.PTAD4
#define PTAD_PTAD5                      _PTAD.Bits.PTAD5
```

So. Let's say that i want a function that sets a bit, like that:

```
void setbit(bit Bit) {
     Bit = 1;
}
```

Of course, the "bit" declaration doesn't work. I would like a declaration that I could use

```
setbit(PTAD_PTAD5)
```

and it would set this bit. I could do

```
void setbit(byte Byte, byte number) {
     Byte |= 1<<(number);
}
```

and send

```
setbit(PTAD,5);
```

That works perfectly, but... that's not what I want, cause I want to do something like Arduino's libraries. Anyone has any idea how to do that in the way I prefered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. C is a pass-by-value language, so even if you could do:

   ```
   void setbit(bit Bit) {
        Bit = 1;
   }
   ```

   it would be a no-op.
2. You can do what you're trying with a function-like-macro:

   ```
   #define setbit(x) do { (x) = 1; } while(0)
   ```

   If you call this macro with `PTAD_PTAD5`, it should work like you expect.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did for the first time. Unfortunately, this macro usage is limited when it comes to embedded systems. But yet, a great idea!

Answer (score 2):

Because you can access the bits in your bitfield individually setting a bit is very easy:

```
_PTAD_PTAD5 = 1;
```

which would, thanks to the `#define _PTAD_PTAD5`, evaluate to

```
_PTAD.Bits.PTAD5 = 1;
```

Note that due to C being a pass-by-value language,

```
void setBit(bit Bit){
    Bit = 1;
}
```

doen't do what you expect. Instead it sets the (function-)local variable `Bit` to one, leaving the variable you send to it unchanged.

Normally you'd use a pointer to a variable you want to change in a function, but because you can't take the address of a bit in a bitfield you can't do that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In C, I do not believe it is possible to access a bitfield as an array.  One idea would be to pass in a enumerated type or constant and switch off its value into 8 different set functions.  Not the cleanest way, but I believe it would work.

```
#define PTAD5  5
...

void setbit(PTADSTR byte, int bit)
{
    switch(bit)
    {
        ...
        case PTAD5  : byte.PTAD5 = 1; break;
        default: ASSERT_ALWAYS(); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
Using the static const qualifier should make sure the memory overhead is about zero

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t* reg;
    uint8_t bitnum;
}bit;

void setbit(bit b)
{
    *b.reg |= (1 << b.bitnum);
}

void clrbit(bit b)
{
    *b.reg &= ~(1 << b.bitnum);
}

static const bit PTAD_PTAD0 = {&PTAD, 0};
static const bit PTAD_PTAD1 = {&PTAD, 1};
static const bit PTAD_PTAD2 = {&PTAD, 2};
static const bit PTAD_PTAD3 = {&PTAD, 3};
static const bit PTAD_PTAD4 = {&PTAD, 4};
static const bit PTAD_PTAD5 = {&PTAD, 5};
static const bit PTAD_PTAD6 = {&PTAD, 6};
static const bit PTAD_PTAD7 = {&PTAD, 7};

int main()
{
    printf("PTAD: %02X\n", PTAD);
    setbit(PTAD_PTAD0);
    printf("PTAD: %02X\n", PTAD);
    clrbit(PTAD_PTAD0);
    printf("PTAD: %02X\n", PTAD);

}
```